# Multiple redirect url not working in slack sso

Tags: single-sign-on, slack, slack-api

We have configured two redirect urls (different domain and valid https urls) in the slack app's oauth and permission section. When we try sso it works fine for the first redirect url and when doing sso for the second one we are getting {"ok":false,"error":"bad_redirect_uri"}. Please help us in resolving the issue

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. The problem is that there are 2 more places where you have to specify the redirect_uri:

1. In the URL where you send users for authentication to get the verification code
   https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=your_scopes&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri&client_id=your_client_app_id
2. When you exchange the verification code for an access token in the POST request to
   https://slack.com/api/oauth.access. If you don't provide the redirect_uri specified in the API method documentation https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.access you will get the {"ok":false,"error":"bad_redirect_uri"} response.

Comment: Thank you! I spent couple of hours debugging this issue.

Comment: @Mircea If we have 2 redirect_uri's, how can we handle this?